# Integrate Hive and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, hadoop, hive

Is there a way to Integrate Hive and AngularJS? I know hive is not for doing simple transactions but, out of curiosity just want to know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unless Angular can communicate over Thrift or JDBC, you need a REST layer in front of HiveServer2